# ElasticSearch for High availability

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 5 node ElasticSearch cluster which locates in 3 DataCenters

DC1:

> - ES01 (*master-eligible, data*)
> - ES02 (*data*)

DC2:

> - ES03 (*master-eligible, data*)
> - ES04 (*data*)

DC3:

> - ES05 (*Master only node*)

so i need to continue Read/Write operations in case of any **DC** Failure
for example if **DC2** is down, cluster now consists of 3 nodes `(ES-01, ES-02 and ES-05)` and it works
so how many shards/ or other settings, like consistency for Reading/Writing should i have to be a DC fault tolerant?

I think the (1 primary shards and 3 replica shards is good for that case) any suggestions?

Comment: Are those real different physical DCs or availability zones inside a single DC ?

Comment: Different Physical

Comment: It's not advised to run a single ES cluster across different data centers. An ES cluster set up for HA is best run in a single DC with different [availability zones](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-design-large-clusters.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to run a single ES cluster across different data centers. An ES cluster set up for HA is best run in a single DC with different [availability zones](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-design-large-clusters.html) (AZ).

Since you have two AZs with data, N primary (the number depends on your volume of data) and 1 replica with [shard allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness) is sufficient. No need to have a copy of the data on each node, just on (at least) one node in each AZ.

ES01 and ES02 should be configured with:

```
node.attr.zone: zone1
```

ES03 and ES04 should be configured with:

```
node.attr.zone: zone2
```

ES01, ES03 and ES05 (i.e. all master-eligible nodes) should be configured with:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: zone
```

This will ensure that the primary and replica shards are balanced across both zones. If zone2 fails, then zone1 still contains a complete copy of the data. What ES is also going to do is to recreate a replica for each primary shard within zone1. If you think you might not have enough capacity in a single zone to contain a full copy of the data, you can use [forced awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#forced-awareness) to prevent ES from assigning the new replica shards to a single zone.

For this you need to add the following line to ES01, ES03 and ES05:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.zone.values: zone1,zone2
```

Comment: i'm create a bug issue btw @val https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/63717

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug... because the cluster state in your snapshot is not the same as in your new cluster... When you restored your snapshot, did you also restore the cluster state?

Comment: Moreover, ES02 and ES04 only need `node.attr.zone`, nothing else

Comment: why only es02 and es04 only need this attribute? above you write it should be on all nodes, and i'm restore the cluster state, but anyway the indexes must placed respect elasticsearch config right?

Comment: Excuse me, I meant `cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes` but copy/pasted the wrong one. my bad

Comment: If you restored the cluster state, then you're overriding those settings... what you need to do is restore your snapshot and then modify those values dynamically via the `cluster/_settings` endpoint. Only then you're going to see the data move around

Comment: Yeah, i'm try to do this exclude state and manually api reroute, but it doesn't work

Comment: Val, What is the rationale for saying "It's not advised to run a single ES cluster across different data centers."  What problem might it cause? Thanks. Pat.

Comment: @PatFahy that's the [official recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-design-large-clusters.html) as connections between data centres typically do not meet low latency expectations.